# Using similar Controllers in areas in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a sport based web site with [Asp.Net Mvc 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4).

The site is being developed to show just one sport data at a time.

The sports have similar datas in common but also they have different datas.

Site supports many sports that’s why, I do not want to use common controllers/views by seperating sports with if statements.

I tried this one:

I have created an area for each sport. I described the controllers in area which are related to that sport.

For example, in Route, name of the controller and area will be stated, firstly it will be searched in area, if it is not there, it will be searched in default(`/Controllers`).

Because the controllers share the same names, Mvc DefaultControllerfactory throws "Ambiguous Controller Name Exception". First I’m searching area, if it cannot be found then I’m searching in default by writing my own Controller factory. You can reach the project by the aid of the this [link](https://github.com/onuralp/AreaBasedControllerFactory)

In this case, my biggest deficiency is; without indicating namespace in route making the same thing in views. So it will search view in area, if it will not be found then it will search in default. Because the project is theme-supported, I use my own themable razor view engine, not default razor view engine. It can be reached by the aid of this [link](https://github.com/onuralp/themedRazorViewEngine)

```
base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new[]
{
  _themeService.Current.BasePath + "/Views/Areas/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
  _themeService.Current.BasePath + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
  _themeService.Current.BasePath + "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml","~/Themes/Default/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
};
```

I updated the object of `AreaViewLocationFormats` of **RazorViewEngine** like this but regardless of the fact that I state area in route, it searches `ViewLocationFormats` instead of `AreaViewLocationFormats` if I do not state namespace.

In this case, how should I separate sports?

Comment: Why don't you just have a table with different types of sports (e.g. "football", "tennis", etc.). Then your actions could take a parameter of the type of sport and return the appropriate view?

Comment: I tihnk the exception is thrown by the mvc DefaultControllerFactory when it tries to figure out which controller to instantiate, it may be worth having a look at multi-tenancy with something like autofac http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration

Comment: @DanielPowell, Because I wan't to use one Assembly for the Controllers, I need common(/Controllers).

Comment: Does each sport have its own Model?

Comment: @ataravati - Yes, it has.

Comment: Why is it not desired to have a different namespace for each area?

Comment: @onuralp the autofac multi-tenancy does support have the tenant controllers all in one assembly, look at the example code on that page

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in a similar scenario is creating a base generic controller like this:

```
public abstract class BaseController<TModel> : Controller where TModel : class, new()
{
   // Controller Actions to be shared by all the controllers that inherit form this one...
}
```

And, then your controllers will be like this:

```
public class TennisController : BaseController<Tennis>
{
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to me, base controller would have the fundamental properties for a "Sports" Controller.